# trying to make a game where if you reach a certain number of guesses the while loop breaks

Tags: python

trying to make a game where if you reach a certain number of guesses the while loop breaks

```
secret_word = "giraffe"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0

while guess != secret_word:
    guess = input("enter guess: ")
    guess_count += 1
    print(guess_count)
    if guess == secret_word:
        print("You win")
    else guess_count == "4":
        print("You lost!")
        break
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost there, you just need to make a few changes. First, you need a break statement within your win condition so the loop stops. Second, you need to change `else` to `elif`, or simply just an `if`. Also, you need to compare `guess_count` to an `int`, not a `str`.

Code:

```
secret_word = "giraffe"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0

while guess != secret_word:
    guess = input("enter guess: ")
    guess_count += 1
    print(guess_count)
    if guess == secret_word:
        print("You win")
        break
    elif guess_count == 4:
        print("You lost!")
        break
```

Output:

```
enter guess: 
dog
1
enter guess: 
dog
2
enter guess: 
dog
3
enter guess: 
dog
4
You lost!
```

Answer (score 1):

I kind of reformated the code, having else with a condition didn't really make sense so I switched it to:

```
secret_word = "giraffe"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
limit = 4

while guess_count < limit:

    guess = input("enter guess: ")
    guess_count += 1
    print(guess_count)

    if guess == secret_word:
        print("Congrats, You Win!!")
        quit()

print('Sorry, too many guesses, you lose! :(')
```

Good luck with the game!!